# Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both package

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Tengo un proyecto en AndroidStudio, y estoy tratando de generar una apk. EL proyecto me lo pasaron funcionando al 100%. No le he modificado NADA.
Solo quiero lanzar la apk. El proyecto ya esta hecho, pero me da estos errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hay 2 librerias que tiene clases con el mismo nombre, podrias agregarle prefijo cuando se use, por ejemplo: import '../../constants.dart' as foo;

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta sucediendo es que `modal_bottom_shet` no esta preparado para `flutter 3.7.x` incluso hay un issue de esto:
https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/325

Como te indican en el issue lo que debes hacer es:
`modal_bottom_sheet:`
Actualizar a `modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre`
Renombra cualquier referencia de la clase `ModalBottomSheetRoute` a `ModalSheetRoute`

Y con ello ya no deberia darte problema alguno.

Si te funciona no olvides marcar la repuesta como aceptada y apoyar con un voto